# Why does encoding an array into json format result in an json object?

Tags: json

This is strange, I've used json encoding arrays and the output is something like [{" etc, but in another code this time the output is "{"1":{".. causing multiple errors. I don't understand what is going on.
this is the part of the code:

```
    $json_arr = json_decode($json_str, true);
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    foreach (array_column($json_arr, 'f') AS $k => $fecha) {
        if($fecha < $ahora){
        unset($json_arr[$k]);
        }
    }
    $json_str = json_encode($json_arr,true);//this will be inserted in the DB table
```

but the $json_str is in the form of  "{"1":{".. but I need in the form of [{".

Here some of the images when debugging:

in orange, the json_str is readed from the BD table
[image: in orange, the json_str is readed from the BD table]
after decoding, you see the json_arr is an array of three elements
[image: after decoding, you see the json_arr is an array of three elements]
after deleting some row, you see json_arr is still an array
[image: after deleting some row, you see json_arr is still an array]
after encoding the json_arr, I get the "{"1":{" format, in other cases of encoding arrays I had the [{" format, which is what I need.
[image: after encoding the json_arr, I get the "{"1":{" format, in other cases of encoding arrays I had the [{" format, which is what I need.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting with an array of 3 arrays, with the indices of 0, 1, and 2.

Then you are deleting the first one. If you compare your 2nd and 3rd screenshots, specifically the popup portion, you'll see that what you have lost is index 0. Your array now starts with index 1.

But in JavaScript, an array **can't** start with index 1. It has to start with index 0, so PHP is encoding it as an object, instead of an array.

If you use the PHP function `array_values()` it will re-index your array and you should be good to go.